# All the combinations of values from the same column

Tags: php, mysql

I have  two table in mysql user and item.

```
 user
ID | session| item | 
1  | 1      |A     | 
2  | 1      |B     | 
3  | 1      |C     | 

item
id | item| price | Images
1  | A   | 10    | link
2  | B   | 5     | link
3  | C   | 5     | link
4  | D   | 5     | link
```

The two tables are correlate from item and in the table "user" I've passed the data form where the user can choose from one to five items. The session is number 1 for example instead alphanumeric value create with function session start.

I display  with select statement and cycle while the images for the items:

> ```
>  $select = "select item, price , images";
>  $from = " from item as i, customer as t"; 
> $where = " where i.item = t.item and t.session = '".$session."'";
> $sql = $select . $from . $where;
> ```

```
 $r=$dbh->prepare($sql);
    $r->execute();
 echo "<ul class=\"tab\"><li class=\"col1\"><strong>item<strong>";

 while($row=$r->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) { 
echo "<img src=\".$row['Images']."\">\n";
}
echo "</li></ul";
```

> Blockquote

In this way I display only the request of the user, in the example session 1  abc.

I like to display all the others combination of the items, ab ac ad abc etc. of the item table but I don't know how set up code php.

Comment: so what is your desired look like, please show the result set. because for session 1 item d is not included i am a little confused.

Comment: In the question I was wrong to insert some part of code. Basically I desire to get the values of the table item and show them in combination ab, ac, ad, abc, abd, acd, abcd, and display the total price for each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are probably other ways of doing this, but here's one in mysql.
the first inner select (T1) just grabs a list of numbers from 1 counting upward to whatever, you can add to this query if you have lots of items where the number of combinations is higher).
the second inner select (T2) just grabs items and price and turns on a bit position for each item, then the outer select inner joins them where the bits of num are turned on it selects that that item.
GROUP_CONCAT() concatenates them, and SUM() just returns the total_price of that combination.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       GROUP_CONCAT(T2.item ORDER BY T2.item SEPARATOR '' ) as items,
       SUM(T2.price) as total_price
FROM
 (SELECT a.num+b.num+c.num+d.num+e.num+f.num+g.num+1 as num
    FROM
    (SELECT 0 as num UNION SELECT 1)a,
    (SELECT 0 as num UNION SELECT 2)b,
    (SELECT 0 as num UNION SELECT 4)c,
    (SELECT 0 as num UNION SELECT 8)d,
    (SELECT 0 as num UNION SELECT 16)e,
    (SELECT 0 as num UNION SELECT 32)f,
    (SELECT 0 as num UNION SELECT 64)g
    ORDER BY num ASC
  )T1
INNER JOIN
   (SELECT item,price,
       @bit := 1 << @shift as bit,
       @shift := @shift + 1 as shift
    FROM item,
       (SELECT @bit := 1,@shift := 0)initial
    ORDER BY id ASC
    )T2
ON T1.num & T2.bit > 0
GROUP BY T1.num
ORDER BY items
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6c2af9/9)

output:

```
items   total_price
A       10
AB      15
ABC     20
ABCD    25
ABD     20
AC      15
ACD     20
AD      15
B        5
BC      10
BCD     15
BD      10
C        5
CD      10
D        5
```

Comment: It's the result I desired. For that I am grateful to you. The complexity of the sql  is beyond my knowledge that I need time to understand all the features. In php I would have had fewer problems, but I'm happy just the same.

Comment: so  you're using the mysql solution then?

Comment: i think if i did it in another language i would still have each item as a bit turned on or off..then have it count from 1 up to the number of items of bits and bit-and them to get my combination string

Comment: At the moment I'll  use your mysql solution.  I try to prepare in Pdo and test  it.  If I find some issue I'll take in mind your useful tip.